# how to display picture in java with giving R,G,B

Tags: java, c++, image, byte, rgb

the value of R or G or B is store in int from 0~255.
I already have all the rgb value of every pixel of the picuture, I want to display the pics base on the r,g,b I already know.

```
    BufferedImage imgnew = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
       //I can get access to the rgb of every pixel by R[x][y],G[x][y],B[x][y]
   //how to calculate the rgb of every pixel?   
       imgnew.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
       }
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel labelnew = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgnew));
    frame.getContentPane().add(labelnew, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

my question is how to calculate the right pix of every pixel, as the rgb is store as int, should I transfer it to byte? if it is, how to do it, if not, is there any other way to calculate pix?
I know someone use

```
         int rgb = 0xff000000 | ((R[x][y] & 0xff) << 16) | (((G[x][y] & 0xff)<< 8) | ((B[x][y] & 0xff);//the way I calcualte the pix is wrong, which lead to the wrong color of pics
```

to calculate rgb, but here the R[x][y] G,B is store in type bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` class returns one or list of pixel by `getRGB()` method, and I have to mention that you don't get it as a 2-demition array like int[width][height], for example if you request pixels from 0,0 to 10,20, then you will get it as a 200-length int[] array.
then you need to break up each int value into 4 byte which represents (argb) of each pixel, so you would do it with `ByteBuffer` class.

here a simple example

```
int imgWidth=1920,imgHeight=1080;
int[] row=new int[imgWidth];//for storing a line of pixels
for(int i=0;i<imgHeight;i++){
  row=img.getRGB(0,i,imgWidth,1,null,0,imgWidth);//get pixel from the current row
  for(int k=0;k<row.length;k++){
    byte[] argb=ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(4).array();//break up int(color) to 4 byte (argb)
    //doing some business with pixel....
  }
    //setting the processed pixel
    //////////////////////////////////////////UPDATED!
    //Preparing each pixel using ByteBuffer class, make an int(pixel) using a 4-lenght byte array
    int rgb=ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0xff,R[x][y]&0xff,G[x][y]&0xff,B[x][y]&0xff}).getInt();
    imgnew.setRGB(x,y,rgb);//this is bettrer to buffer some pixel then set it to the image, instead of set one-by-one
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    //img.setRGB(0,i,imgWidth,1,row,0,imgWidth)
}
```

also check this [example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc) too

Comment: I don't want get rgb of a pics, but I know every rgb of a pixel, and want to display this

Comment: @Rebecca your welcome, I have to say I missed something with the code(please check the updated answer) and I hope you have solved the issue well. and the issue was that after wrapping the byte[] array into the int via `wrap()` method, you have to call the `getInt()` method too that I missed.